# Jquery Hover Flickering issue

Tags: jquery, hover

Hope u people will be fine. Here is my basic code:

http://jsfiddle.net/kr9pY/7/

in this demo you can see when we hover on div with id="container", a div with class="nav" fades in. But the problem is that after doing this if i hover on div with class="nav" the div fades out and in again, and if i mover cursor slightly within .nav div, it repeats this behavior repeatedly. I don't want to this behaviour when we hover on .nav div or mover cursor within this div.

Thank, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

   $("#containerNav").hover(
   function() { $('.nav').stop(true, true).fadeIn(); },
   function() { $('.nav').stop(true, true).fadeOut(); }
   );
   });
```

Taken from http://api.jquery.com/stop/

I changed the markup to add a containing div as well which stops a mouse leave being called.

```
<div id="containerNav">
    <div class="nav"><a class="prev" href="#">Prev</a> <a class="next" href="#">Next</a>  </div>
    <div id="container">
        Some Content in Container
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when you hover over the controls your not doing a mouseleave which causes the blink.

http://jsfiddle.net/kr9pY/9/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but unfortunately this is also not working. There is no effect of this change.

Comment: Weird.. the only time i really notice it "blink" is when my mouse is over the elements that appear, which i think is because your doing a mouseleave on the div, as soon as you hover over the nav elements. I just edited my answer putting the nav elements below the div and I don't seem to get the blinking.

Comment: +1 for editing in the same containing div idea I was about to post.

Comment: thanks, just edited for the last time to include the containing div as the only answer, considering thats what he was asking, no need to change the layout of his markup.

Comment: Thanks Loktar, you rock. Now this solution is working fine. Problem solved by only addition of a container div.

Comment: nice solution, but you don't really need to have two functions in hover since you can use `.fadeToggle()`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/kr9pY/10/) (i also updated the css a little)

Comment: oh nice.. have never seen/used fadeToggle makes it a lot more simplified.

Comment: @mekwall: hmm.. nice its more simpler.